# Product Filter By Date Attributes Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database

So i have created a attributes is future_date

[image: Date]

Now i want to filter product based on this attribute. I want to filter product whatever match with this date. For an example we setup a date 5th June and today is 28th May. But when i filter at 5th June this product will be in filtered list.
How can i achive this?

Answer (score 2):

If You want to get product collection which has future date is current date,

You the following code :

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('future_date', array('eq' => $today))
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->load();
```

I think it will help you..